# Parse through text files and write into CSV

Tags: java, parsing, csv

I have about 100 different text files in the same format. Each file has observations about certain events at certain time periods for a particular person. I am trying to parse out the relevant information for a few individuals for each of the different text files. Ideally, I want to get parse through all this information and create a CSV file (eventually to be imported into Excel) with all the information I need from ALL the text files. Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated. I would prefer to use java...but any simpler methods are appreciated.

The log files are structured as below: changed data to preserve private information

|||ID||NAME||TIME||FIRSTMEASURE^DATA||SECONDMEASURE^DATA|| etc...

TIME appears like 20110825111501 for 2011, 08/25 11:15:01 AM

Comment: You'll have to give us more of a clue about the format of the files that you want to parse - how they are structured, what you want to get etc etc...

Comment: What exactly is your problem? If you know how the read and write files, why don't you just iterate over the text files, parse them and write the parse results into a single CSV file? - Or is it the parsing that poses a problem?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is I'm not sure how to parse through all this data (while only looking for a few lines of information) and store this information all into a single CSV for each individual. I want the columns to be the measures and each row would be an observation for that measure at each time period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps in Java:

1. Open the file using [FileReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html)
2. You could also wrapped the FileReader with [BufferedReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and use readLine() method to read the file line by line
3. For each line you need to  parse it. You know best the data definition of each line, to help you might be able to use various String functions or [Java Regex](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
4. You could do the same thing for the Date. Check if you could utilize [DateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html)
5. Once you parse the data, you could start building your CSV File using CSVParser mentioned above or write it your own using [FileOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)
6. When you are ready to to convert to Excel, you could use [Apache POI for Excel](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html)

Let me know if you need further clarification

Answer (score 0):

Just to parse through the text file and use [CSVParser](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVPrinter.html) from apache to write to a csv file. Additionally if you want to write in to excel, you can simply use [Apache POI](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVPrinter.html) or [JXL](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SuperCSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/) to parse the file into a bean and
also to create a csv-file.